# get name of file from file path using AppleScript

Tags: applescript, filesystem

I am trying to get the name of file using AppleScript with the following code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set filename to name of "/Users/mainuser/Desktop/Test/shot.png" // should return  shot.png
    display dialog filename
end tell
```

I am getting an error saying:

```
error "Can’t get name of \"/Users/mainuser/Desktop/Test/shot.png\"." number -1728 from name of "/Users/mainuser/Desktop/Test/shot.png"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the *file pathname* from your question, here is the AppleScript *code* that should work.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fileName to name of (POSIX file "/Users/mainuser/Desktop/Test/shot.png" as alias)
    display dialog fileName
end tell
```

A more direct way of the above scenario is:

Syntax:

```
set fileName to name of (info for "/path/to/file")
display dialog fileName
```

Example (using the pathname in your question):

```
set fileName to name of (info for "/Users/mainuser/Desktop/Test/shot.png")
display dialog fileName
```

The shortest way to display the *name* of a *file* from its *pathname* in a *dialog box* is:

Syntax:

```
display dialog name of (info for "/path/to/file")
```

Example (using the pathname in your question):

```
display dialog name of (info for "/Users/mainuser/Desktop/Test/shot.png")
```

Comment: Really awesome answer! Just a little subquestion. I am struggling with the reasoning behind using (POSIX file "url" as alias). What exactly does POSIX do and why use alias at the end?

Comment: You do not necessarily need to use the first form I presented. The second form. `set fileName to name of (info for "/path/to/file")` works without the need of `POSIX file` and `as alias`. Because the comments have a 600 character limit it is difficult to explain the differences and reasons why one might use one way over the other and this is better left to the User educating themselves via reading the [AppleScript Language Guide PDF](https://applescriptlibrary.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/applescriptlanguageguide-2013.pdf) and other books on AppleScript. The short answer is because it works. :)